# In what order does the Temporal Villain check off numbers on the Anachronometer?

Tags: time-and-temp

The numbers 13 through 20 on the Anachronometer are reserved for being filled in by the Temporal Villain at a pace determined by their TVI. They are grouped in pairs of two and have one box *not* threatening paradox and one *indeed* threatening paradox.

Now, it says in the book: "the GM will periodically check off the lowest circle on this end of the Anachronometer".

So, if I – as GM – have checked off the first circle for "19-20", is the next circle I check off the first one in the line "17-18" or is it the second one for "19-20"?

The latter would mean, that already from the second TVI time step on, the temps would always risk paradox! While this would be hilarious, devastating fun for me, I think it might be a bit hard on the temps.

So, how is this supposed to work? Do you risk paradox after 2 or 5 TVI time steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first TVI tick fills in 19.  Nothing happens, other than the temps realizing they're on a timer if they didn't already know.
- The second TVI tick fills in 20.  Now both 19 and 20 threaten paradox, and the GM rolls the paradox dice.
- Basically, every even tick fills in a dot to the right of the line, which causes a roll and introduces two more numbers that threaten paradox.  Every time a new dot gets filled in on the Threatens Paradox side on the anachrometer, the GM rolls for paradox.

Paradox is automatically risked after a paradox die is locked in.  The fact that there are numbers threatening paradox isn't sufficient, merely making the chance of a locked paradox die more likely. A paradox die is locked only when the GM rolls the paradox dice and one (or more) of them matches a number that threatens paradox.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought, they would roll every time and ,thusly, was confused about the pace at which things get really bad.

Comment: Uh, my follow-up question, because it is not clear to me from the rules text: Do you roll Paradox Dice every time, you fill in a circle to the right of the Anachronometer line? I.e. do you roll upon your fourth "1" in the matrix?

Comment: Yes, every time a dot gets filed past the line.  I just clarified my answer to reflect that.  The temps are pushing their luck every time they pick a result that's already been used twice.